# Have a mutual dependency situation for geany installation

Tags: rpm, circular-dependency

I tried to install geany rpm on centOS 6.7,
Here is the prompt:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -Uvh geany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
geany-libgeany = 1.27-1.el6 is needed by geany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64
libgeany.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -Uvh geany-libgeany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
geany = 1.27-1.el6 is needed by geany-libgeany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Those two rpms are mutually dependent.How can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite common. You just need the to install them together:

```
rpm -Uvh geany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm geany-libgeany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Or even better:

```
yum install geany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm geany-libgeany-1.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Never thought about that. Thx!